# Can I use Vcc to represent constant 1

Tags: circuit-design

I just started studying circuit design as part of my computer science program. I am trying to use a  8-to-1 MUX. My goal is that the MUX will output 1 only when the inputs (selectors) are 001, and the rest are 0.

I understand that I need to put 1 to D0 input and 0 to all other inputs. Before using a professional software, I am able to draw something to represent the constant. However, as per the requirement of the instructor, I have to switch to Quartus where I can only find Vcc and GND.

From what I have heard, Vcc is a representation of 1 and GND is a representation of 0. As a result, I am not sure if I can connect Vcc to D0 and GND to the rest of the inputs?

PS: I also put GND to the enable port as I assume it is 0 and MUX takes its inverse, so it will thus enable the MUX. Not sure if I am correct

Comment: Yes. But hardwiring the MUX inputs like that should be a hint that there's a much simpler implementation...

Comment: >>>  PS: I also put GND to the enable port as I assume it is 0 and MUX takes its inverse, so it will thus enable the MUX. Not sure if I am correct      -------------           We can't comment on this unless you identify your MUX.   "Enable" could be low or high, there is no 'standard'

Comment: Look at a data sheet of an IC, this will tell you the logic levels (also google logic levels) they usually are 0.3*Vcc is low and 0.7*Vcc is high or something like that.